# Laravel Auth register route or login route not found

Tags: php, laravel

I have a brand new Laravel project and I ran the command to turn auth on and set all my routes and controllers but when I click on the standard login/register button I get view auth.register not found and auth.login not found. I checked my views folder and I see register.blade.php and login.blade.php in there. I checked the routes in the Router class and noticed this was in there:

`$this->get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');`

I do not see anything called AuthController. I see RegisterController but there  is no method in there called showRegistrationForm.

I have `Auth::routes();` included in my web.php file in routes folder. I am not sure why these two pages are not loading to show the user the forms.

Comment: Are you sure you did give the `php artisan make:auth` command? Cause it seems like auth scaffolding is missing. What do you have in your `resources/views/auth` directory? (if you have one)

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? `AuthController` used to be there in previous versions like 5.2, but now Laravel uses separate controllers for login, registration, etc. Which file contains that line in your post that calls `AuthController`? Did you import that from an older project?

Comment: I am using version 5.7. I have a passwords directory and then login, register, and verify blade files in the resources/views/auth directory.

Comment: And which file has that line you posted which calls the AuthController?

Comment: @newUserName02 that came in the Illuminate/Routing/Router.php file

Comment: i have exact same problem now. i have no route for register while using Auth::routes(). all other routes are working and available but no sign of register. view for register and registerController are also present but no sign of showRegistration form in registerController. this is so new issue that almost no help available on internet